# Calling a function from one ViewController to another

Tags: ios, swift, oop, swift4

I have two functions that i would like to call in another `ViewController`.  I don't want to write the same code in the other `Viewcontroller`. I have tried creating a `ViewController` object and call the two methods this but keep getting crashes. I have also tried extending the `UIViewController` but no luck. How can i go on about

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class PrivacyPolicyController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        createWebView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadURL(url: "https://www.apple.com")
    }

    func loadWebView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView

    }

    func loadURL(url: String) {
        guard let myURL = URL(string: url) else { return }
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

I wanna call `loadURL` and `loadWebView` functions in this `ViewController`

import UIKit
import WebKit

```
class TermsAndConditionsController: UIViewController{

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

The `ViewController` where actions are performed

```
import UIKit

class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func termsAndConditionsTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let termsAndConditions = TermsAndConditionsController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(termsAndConditions, animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func privacyPolicyTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let privacyPolicy = PrivacyPolicyController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(privacyPolicy, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: How are the two viewcontrollers related? Do they perform the same task, i.e. load a URL in a webview? If that's the case I don't see why you need two different classes for this. Why not use the same class for both?

Comment: @andlin They do, one displays privacy policy and the terms and conditions

Comment: If the only difference between them is that they load different URLs I recommend that you use the same viewcontroller for both.

Comment: @andlin i have different buttons that display each one of them from another `ViewController`

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. When tapping the first button, you create an instance of the viewcontroller and set the URL to load. You do the same for the other button, but set a different URL instead. Creating different viewcontroller classes just because you load different URLs is not good design. What if you want to load a third URL? Do you create a third viewcontroller class then? See what I mean?

Comment: If you post the code that's executed when the buttons are tapped it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @andlin i have posted it

Comment: I added an answer with my suggested solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment, use the same viewcontroller for both the Privacy Policy and T&C:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class MyWebViewController: UIViewController {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func loadWebView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        self.view.addSubview(self.webView)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    func loadURL(url: String) {
        guard let myURL = URL(string: url) else { return }
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL)
        if (self.webView == nil) {
            self.loadWebView()
        }
        self.webView.load(myRequest)
    }

}
```

Then:

```
import UIKit

class MakeItHappenViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func termsAndConditionsTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let termsAndConditions = MyWebViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(termsAndConditions, animated: true)
        termsAndConditions.loadURL("http://someurl.com")
    }

    @IBAction func privacyPolicyTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let privacyPolicy = MyWebViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(privacyPolicy, animated: true)
        privacyPolicy.loadURL("http://someotherurl.com")
    }

}
```

Comment: @adlin this is crashing, saying it found nil when unwrapping optional. It lists the url in the debugging console

Comment: @adlin This works perfect, thanks a lot, works perfect. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can create Base class(Which inherits UIViewController) for that and make your both view controller inherit the base class. That way you can have both the methods in both classes and you can just make calls to them

```
    Class BaseClass: UIViewController{
 var webView: WKWebView
 func loadWebView() {
      let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
      webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
     webView.uiDelegate = self
}

func loadURL(url: String) {
    guard let myURL = URL(string: url) else { return }
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL)
    webView.load(myRequest)
}}
```

The base class now has all the required methods for creating adding and realoading url for web view. Now for view controller classes.

```
Class PrivacyPolicyController: BaseClass, WKUIDelegate {func methodWhereYouwantToCallWebviewMthods(){
 self.loadWebView()
 self.loadURL()
 self.view = self.webView}}
```

Same for other class

```
class TermsAndConditionsController: BaseClass{func methodWhereYouwantToCallWebviewMthods(){
 self.loadWebView()
 self.loadURL()
 self.view = self.webView}
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}}
```